# Using Retrofit to get JSON

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, muzei

I'm currently trying to build a Muzei extension using Retrofit like the example Roman uses in his example.

I can't really get my head around Retrofit, however this is what I have

**ArtSource.java**

```
public class ArtSource extends RemoteMuzeiArtSource {
    private static final String TAG = "The Muzei Collection";
    private static final String SOURCE_NAME = "The Muzei Collection";

    private static final int ROTATE_TIME_MILLIS = 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // rotate every 3 hours

    public ArtSource() {
        super(SOURCE_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setUserCommands(BUILTIN_COMMAND_ID_NEXT_ARTWORK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTryUpdate(int reason) throws RetryException {
        String currentToken = (getCurrentArtwork() != null) ? getCurrentArtwork().getToken() : null;

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setServer("http://elliothesp.co.uk")
                .build();

        ArtService service = restAdapter.create(ArtService.class);
        PhotosResponse response = service.getPopularPhotos();

   if (response == null || response.photos == null) {
        throw new RetryException();
    }

    if (response.photos.size() == 0) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No photos returned from API.");
        scheduleUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis() + ROTATE_TIME_MILLIS);
        return;
    }

        Random random = new Random();
        Photo photo;
        String token;
        while (true) {
            photo = response.photos.get(random.nextInt(response.photos.size()));
            token = Integer.toString(photo.id);
            if (response.photos.size() <= 1 || !TextUtils.equals(token, currentToken)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        publishArtwork(new Artwork.Builder()
                .title(photo.title)
                .byline(photo.user)
                .imageUri(Uri.parse(photo.url))
                .token(token)
                .viewIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")))
                .build());

        scheduleUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis() + ROTATE_TIME_MILLIS);
    }
}
```

**ArtService.java**

```
interface ArtService {
    @GET("/muzei.php")
    PhotosResponse getPopularPhotos();

    static class PhotosResponse {
        List<Photo> photos;
    }

    static class Photo {
        int id;
        String user;
        String title;
        String url;

    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to take the JSON from http://elliothesp.co.uk/muzei.php and pass each item to publishArtwork.  It runs the exception as it cannot find any photos from the JSON feed and I am not sure how to get that working

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xAVp3CKs

Comment: Is this the whole log? And what is at the line 62 of your ArtSource.java (it's not listed completely)

Comment: also you can try to make your interface public

Comment: photo = response.photos.get(random.nextInt(response.photos.size()));

Comment: btw, the example to pull from the 500px.com api json is here: https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/tree/master/example-source-500px/src/main/java/com/example/muzei/examplesource500px

Comment: I've added in an exception, it no longer crashes, as it now logs an exception saying that no photo was found at the json feed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `JSON` format of your `response` doesn't fit your interface, it should be:

```
interface service {
    @GET("/muzei.php")
    Map<String,Photo> getPopularPhotos();

    static class Photo {
        int id;
        String user;
        String title;
        String url;

    }
}
```

And `response`:

```
Map<String, Photo> response = service.getPopularPhotos();
```

Then just re-write your code after you get `response` to iterate through it

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling that was the issue but I didn't understand it will enough.   Your answer just made it all very clear though